# Is transactionManager Bean created by default when we annotate our spring boot class as @EnabletransactionManagement?

Tags: java, spring, database, spring-boot, transactionmanager

Is transactionManager Bean created by default when we annotate our spring boot class as @EnabletransactionManagement ?

Comment: I hope this doc will help you  - https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/EnableTransactionManagement.html#:~:text=Annotation%20Type%20EnableTransactionManagement&text=Enables%20Spring's%20annotation%2Ddriven%20transaction,management%20or%20reactive%20transaction%20management.

Comment: so if  we don't create a  transaction Manager  bean in config class  and only annotate the @EnableTransactionManagement by default the transaction Manager bean will be created in the context?

Comment: could you please refer this article, https://www.baeldung.com/transaction-configuration-with-jpa-and-spring